# Убрать всё с input

Tags: css3, css

Подскажите, как убрать все стили (предоставленные браузером) с `input[type=text]`.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/WeUeC/

display:none

Comment: Я не лентяй. А как при. вводе текста сделать стили. Ну на пример когда я кликаю это :active, а когда текст ввожу это?

Comment: Разве что :focus - элементы, на которых фокус.
Про псевдо-классы тут - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: @Vlmake ну я надеюсь, что ты хоть перед собой честен

Answer (score 0):

outline: 0;
уберет все стили с инпута

Answer (score 0):

Примените свойство

```
appearance: none;
```

Comment: 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык. 2. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]